# Booting problem in Ubuntu 15.10 , 14.04

Tags: boot, 15.10

I want to use Ubuntu 15.10, but every time the computer boots it shows something like:
"SYSLINUX Peter Anvin at el"
I want to fix this error to use Ubuntu.

BIOS -> Pendrive is 1st Boot Disk.
I'm using UNetBootin and it records data in the pendrive.
I downloaded 32bit version.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Have you tried [checking your hashes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes)?

Comment: Ok,it shows:
51b53fa15c0b89948bbaba311d64a962 *ubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-i386.iso
And the md5sum in terminal correct,but still not booting.

Comment: Why 32 bit? Very, very old system with 2GB of RAM or less? Or new lightweight system. If so you proably need Lubuntu.  I might try one of the other flash drive creator programs. Some just seem to cause issue, or some flash drives. Or even perhaps some combination of installer & brand flash drive. And a change helps.

Comment: My computer has 2GB of RAM,i tried to install the iso with YUMI[by .wine],but the error keeps appearing.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a random issue with 'Unetbootin' and 'startup disk creator'. I used a Kingston 16gb 2.0 usb drive to boot Ubuntu 15.10 installation image (ubuntu-15.10-desktop-i386.iso). All that appeared at boot was:

```
"SYSLINUX Peter Anvin  etc."

BOOT ERROR
```

After searching all the articles with no luck, observed at the command line that the drive itself was marked rw only and although Ubuntu showed it as bootable, the drive itself was not executable. Used `chmod +x` on `/dev/sdc` and drive worked perfectly installing the existing iso image of 15.10 that Unetbootin and Startup disk creator both configured it with. No other changes needed to be made to the drive or the software image.

Problem is that after installation the usb drive becomes rw only again as follows:

```
$ls -la /dev/sdc

brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 32 Mar 19 11:34 /dev/sdc

$sudo chmod +x /dev/sdc 

$ls -la /dev/sdc

brwxrwx--x 1 root disk 8, 32 Mar 19 11:34 /dev/sdc
```

I tried the install process 3 times with the same results. Each time I received the error was able to make the drive executable from the command line and it worked on reboot. There seems to be an intermittent issue with making the executable setting persistent on the usb drive as the condition and its resulting error can be made consistently repeatable.